# Joomla! CSS caching not deleting or refreshing

Tags: css, caching, joomla

I'm trying to clear/delete the cache on a Joomla! website. I have deleted cache from the dashboard, through FTP, updating the htaccess file, everything else I can think of. The styles are now being injected directly onto the index.php file through Javascript on top having the stylesheet still linking. Am I missing something? How can I delete the cache and have my styles updated?

I have the styles added through the template editor in the dashboard (which are NOT the currently applied styles).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you have a [wordpress.se] SE and [drupal.se] SE acount, but no [joomla.se] SE.  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

If your site is hosted in Cpanel. Check if **Mod_pagespeed** is enabled. May be it will be the reason why all CSS files are combined to load page fast.